# javascript splice don't work properly

Tags: javascript

I want to remove an element from array, but splice method remove all elemts from star index till the end of array.

I have this code:

```
function basketItemRemove(obj, id) {
...

    if (id == 0)
        tempBasketList.splice(id, id + 1);
    else
        tempBasketList.splice(id, id);
...
}
```

I check id 0, because splice don't remove with index 0. Then `splice(id, id);` properly work only with second element of array, but if element is third or higher then it delete all till the end of array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to [`splice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12) is **how many** elements to remove, not the point at which to stop removing them. If you want to remove one element, use `1`:

```
tempBasketList.splice(id, 1);
```

> I check id 0, because splice don't remove with index 0

It does, but not if that's what you give for the second argument, because it means to remove zero items.

The signature of `splice` (from the link above) explained:

```
splice(start, deleteCount [ , item1 [ , item2 [ , … ] ] ] )
```

- `start`: Where to start doing things (the index)
- `deleteCount`: How many to delete at that location
- `item1`, `item2`, `item3`: Optional items to add at that location (after having deleted, if `deleteCount > 0`)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is:

> `array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])`

This means that if you need to remove only one single element, the second argument should be `1`:

```
tempBasketList.splice(id, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will create a prototype to make thing more easier,

```
Array.prototype.delete = function (obj) {
    var index = this.indexOf(obj);// Get the index of object
    this.splice(index, 1);// delete it
};
```

and then,

```
tempBasketList.remove(obj)
```

Comment: You just need to define Array.prototype.delete once and you can use tempBasketList.remove(obj) or anyarray.remove at every where